# Test $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\Big(1-n \sin(n^{-1})\Big)$ for convergence with asymptotic comparison

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, asymptotics

Suppose we want to test the following series for convergence

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\Big(1-n \sin(n^{-1})\Big)$$

I have found a solution that uses the asymptotic comparison test and uses the following equivalence:
$$ \sin(n^{-1})\sim {1\over n} - {1\over6n^3};$$
$$1-n \sin(n^{-1}) \sim {1\over6n^2}$$
So the series converges absolutely because ${1\over6n^2}$ converges absolutely.

My question is, why choose ${1\over n} - {1\over6n^3}$ and not some different equivalence? If we used ${1\over n} - {1\over n^2}$, the resulting series would have been:

$$\sin(n^{-1})\sim {1\over n} - {1\over n^2};$$

$$ 1-n \sin(n^{-1}) \sim {1\over n},$$
which diverges and so the result would be incorrect. Why is that?

Comment: That was written keeping in mind the taylor series of $\sin x = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}$

Comment: you should use a valid asymptotic expansion.

Comment: You cannot choose freely here. Write the third order Taylor polynomial of $\sin(x)$ at $x=0$ and substitute $x=1/n$. What do you get?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I get exactly ${1\over n} - {1\over6n^3}$. Thanks, i start to see now.

Comment: More to the point, it is correct to write either:
$\sin(\frac{1}{n})$~$\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{6n^3}$ or $\sin(\frac{1}{n})$~$\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{6n^{300}}$, the thing is equivalency should be used very carefully, and you should never write a term and another one neglictable next to it, because it becomes meaningless. What you should write is:
$\frac{1}{n}-\sin(\frac{1}{n})$~ $\frac{1}{6n^3}$, which is completely different. There should always be only one term on the side of the estimate (that is, usually the right side)